# Weird typewriter sound as I type into a textbox (wpf) in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, audio

I've made a pretty simple WPF windows with a textbox in it.
As I type in it it gives me this weird typewriter-sound.
Any idea why? And how can I stop it from doing it?

Comment: It automatically corrects typing mistakes.

Comment: It's not because of the keyboard... it's on other computers too. :P

Typewriter is well... difficult... let's say a computer without screen and with less or no memory. ;)
Just this white flat memory... called... "paper"...
weird stuff!

Comment: What a strange and unique world we live in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the most terrible "error" I ever had. :-D
Everytime I typed something in my textbox I refreshed a webview. That refreshing made this sound.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no built-in functionality in WPF to automatically generate a weird typewriter sound in text boxes, you basically have 2 choices:

1. Remove the code that you have in the text changed event that plays the weird typewriter sound.
2. Make sure that you don't have any third party applications that generates weird typewriter sounds on your system.

Comment: Oh is it maybe possible that it's cause of the WPF Toolkit from codeplex? I just remembered that I installed it...

Answer (score 1):

As Magnus mentions, you may need to check the event handler for the TextChanged, KeyDown, and KeyUp events for the TextBox(es) that give you that response. It is possible to code something to make a sound on every KeyDown or KeyUp event, but there is no setting in Windows to do that, nor does WPF do something like that by default.

I did find some articles that show how to make a "clicky" keyboard, and they all were meant for mobile or touch devices. You may want to check to see if the project config file has a target device set to either one of those.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that by default in WPF.  Check your system sounds in your Control Panel.  Either that or one of your officemates is playing some sort of trick on you.

Comment: Oh is it maybe possible that it's cause of the WPF Toolkit from codeplex?
I just remembered that I installed it...

Comment: Doubt it.  I also use the WPF toolkit with no issues.  Make sure you have the latest stable build, though, and not some nightly...

Answer (score 0):

In case it could help, but I doubt of that: Is that limited to the application you develop? I had this coupled with light display anomalies and it was the graphic card that was dying. The sound was associated with mouse moves on some windows.